# Get context.user.profile from item lock owner

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Here's my problem:
This pipeline was overriden in an attempt to display the users real name.

```
Sitecore.Pipelines.GetContentEditorWarnings.IsLocked
```

The change was simply to use the `Item.getUpdatedBy()` instead of `Item.Locking.GetOwner()` of lock because the thought was that anyone who updated the item would have to lock the item. The `getUpdatedBy()` also displyed the `Context.user.profile.fullname` along side of the user name. The problem is that a user can update an item without actually locking the item so you'd see the lock field filled with a different user than the last updated user.

What I'd like todo:
I need to display the item's lock owner fullname (`context.user.profile.fullname`). How do I get the `context.user.profile` from the lock owner (`Item.Locking.GetOwner()`) information?

let me know if i need to be more clear.
Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Item.Locking.GetOwner()` method just returns the username of the person who holds the lock. From the username you will need to get the user and then their profile. There are probably a few ways to handle this... here is one.

```
string username = theItem.Locking.GetOwner();
Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName(theItem, false);
Sitecore.Security.UserProfile profile = user.Profile;
string fullName = profile.FullName;
```

Comment: Thanks Sean, just what I needed!

Comment: FYI - I can accomplish the above in a few less lines of code..`var ownerUserProfile = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName(item.Locking.GetOwner(), false).Profile;`

Comment: Sure. I broke it out for clarity.

Comment: I hope to be. I'm waiting to hear back from Sitecore.